# Python первая значащая цифра в элементах массива

Tags: python, массивы, numpy

Есть два массива (ниже a и b) с произвольными положительными числами. Вообще говоря, они не обязательно целые, но если вдруг требуется, можно добавить и такое условие. Требуется получить третий массив (ниже - c), в котором:

- c(i) = 1, если (первая цифра в b(i) > первой цифры в a(i) И длина целой части a(i) == длине целой части b(i)) или длина целой части b(i) больше длины целой части a(i);
- c(i) = -1, в аналогичной ситуации, только a(i) и b(i) меняются местами;
- c(i) = 0 во всех остальных случаях.

Интересует, по возможности, максимально эффективный по быстродействию алгоритм.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([11, 17, 183, 736, 89, 107, 1231, 1928])
b = np.array([10, 21, 179, 799, 81, 99,  1971, 2010])

c = np.array([0, 1, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 1])
```

Comment: можете пояснить по поводу `107` и `99` - длина целой части у `107` больше...

Comment: Или я чего-то не понял, или все вроде корректно - так как длина целой части a(i) > длины целой части b(i), выполняется условие "в аналогичной ситуации, только a(i) и b(i) меняются местами; ", поэтому c(i) = -1

Comment: Хотя, наверное, понял: вместо "если первая цифра в b(i) > первой цифры в a(i)" следует читать ("если первая цифра в b(i) > первой цифры в a(i)" И "длина целой части a(i) == длине целой части b(i)")

Comment: а чем ваш алгоритм сравнения отличается от обычного целочисленного?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Рассмотрите логику, реализованную в следующем коде (работает, но нужно добавить проверки и вообще окультурить, т.к. я не спец в Python):

Найдём длину чисел через десятичный логарифм ( здесь длина уменьшена на 1, т.е. для 107 получим 2)

Сравним длины, если по ним всё ясно, вернем результат

Иначе выделяем целочисленным делением первую цифру с использованием таблицы степеней десяти

```
import numpy as np

def digcomp(aa, bb):
    table = np.array([1,10,100,1000,10000,100000,1000000])
    la = int(np.log10(aa))
    lb = int(np.log10(bb))
    if la > lb:
        return(-1)
    elif lb > la:
         return(1)
    else:
       da = aa // table[la]
       db = bb // table[la]
       if da > db:
           return(-1)
       elif db > da:
           return(1)
       else:
          return(0)


a = np.array([11, 17, 183, 736, 89, 107, 1231, 1928])
b = np.array([10, 21, 179, 799, 81, 99,  1971, 2010])
c = np.array([2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2])
for i in range(len(a)):
    c[i] = digcomp(a[i], b[i])
print(c)
```

Comment: красивая идея с `log10` +1

Comment: Спасибо. Но, все же, циклы в практически любом виде в моем случае - не вариант, а вот как такую логику (и да, log10 - красиво) перенести на функции numpy для быстродействия (речь может идти о матрицах 100x300x200, например) - не очень понимаю.

Comment: Так или иначе, log10 решил самую сложную для меня проблему, остальное вроде получилось, добавлю ответ. Благодарю еще раз :).

Answer (score 1):

Я бы воспользовался Pandas:

```
In [10]: import pandas as pd

In [11]: sa = pd.Series(a.astype(str))

In [12]: sb = pd.Series(b.astype(str))

In [13]: res = np.where(sa.str[0] > sb.str[0], 1, np.where(sa.str[0] < sb.str[0], -1, 0))
```

Результат:

```
In [14]: res
Out[14]: array([ 0, -1,  0,  0,  0, -1,  0, -1])
```

Замеры скорости для массива из 80.000 элементов:

```
In [15]: sa = pd.concat([sa] * 10**4)

In [16]: sb = pd.concat([sb] * 10**4)

In [17]: sa.shape
Out[17]: (80000,)

In [18]: sb.shape
Out[18]: (80000,)

In [19]: %timeit np.where(sa.str[0] > sb.str[0], 1, np.where(sa.str[0] < sb.str[0], -1, 0))
174 ms ± 5.25 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

Получилось хотя и длинновато, но только с операциями умножения/сложения/возведения в степень матриц,

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([11, 17, 183, 736, 89, 107, 1231, 1928])
b = np.array([10, 21, 179, 799, 81, 99,  1971, 2010])    

la = np.floor(np.log10(a))
lb = np.floor(np.log10(b))   

arr_plus_1  = np.ones (8)
arr_minus_1 = np.ones (8) * -1
arr_zero    = np.zeros(8)
t           = np.ones (8) * 10

x = arr_zero + (lb > la) * arr_plus_1 \
    + (la > lb) * arr_minus_1 \
    + (la == lb) * (np.floor(b / np.power(t, la)) > np.floor(a / np.power(t, la))) \
    + (la == lb) * (np.floor(a / np.power(t, la)) > np.floor(b / np.power(t, la)))
print(x)
```

```
[ 0.  1.  0.  0.  0. -1.  0.  1.]
```